# How to make an object moves by holding a key on the keyboard down (ex: 'W' key) in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need the object moves only when I'm holding W key on the keyboard and once I release the key, It must be stop smoothly.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Car : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddForce (transform.forward*100*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by : Making a loop ?

Comment: The `Update` method is called `once per frame` as the default comment states, so when you hold in W, each frame, e.g `60 times / second @ 60fps` will execute the code within the `Update` method.

Comment: I mean that i want to move it only when, when i press W and when W is not pressed it has to stop.

Comment: Is stop immediately or slowly?

Comment: i want that when I press W, my car has to move a little bit forward, then stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using GetKey instead of GetKeyDown

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Car : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddForce (transform.forward*100*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not like I had already said and explained that before [`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69767115/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

[`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) is only `true` **ONCE** in the frame where the button is pressed.

It sounds like you rather want to use [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) which is `true` every frame **WHILE** the button stays pressed.

In general though you should apply forces etc rather in `FixedUpdate`

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rb.AddForce(rb.GetRelativeVector(Vector3.forward) * 100 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    // If you want it to stop immediately - not very realistic though
    // and would require more checks like is it actually on the ground etc
    //else
    //{
    //    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    //}
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's his problem. Add force results in velocity,